# Track information about shared post at Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to track information about shared post from my website with Facebook?
Scenario:
User click "Repost" button at my site, fill comment at "Post to Facebook" window and click "Share". After this I need to track info about this post: reposts and people, who do it, is it deleted, comments and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this, unless you authorize the User with the apropriate permissions and check his stream once in a while - either with a cron job or with the [Realtime API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/).

You can also try using Insights for your domain: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains

Comment: No one "activityID" such as at G+ API, using which it is possible to see additional info about post mapped to this activityID?

Comment: without authorization, you don´t get any id, no

Comment: can you clarify some things, please? What you mean at "you authorize the User with the apropriate permissions"? User come to me and login with OpenAuth, is it another authorization? Or I must create specific users at my Facebook APP and i can check only theirs posts? Or other?

Comment: appropriate permissions means user_status or read_stream - you have to ask for it in the login process of an app.

Comment: understand, thanks. Is it some example for check post info if we already have this activityID?

Comment: you really need to start using the facebook docs, it´s all in there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post?locale=en_GB